# regexp does not work as expected in Octave

Tags: octave

I have downloaded the "NYU Depth V2" dataset and toolbox from [here](https://cs.nyu.edu/~silberman/datasets/nyu_depth_v2.html). In the toolbox there is a script called `get_synched_frames.m`. I do not have Matlab, so I have tried running it in Octave. Unfortunately, it does not work as expected.

The line

```
% Faster than matlab's Dir function for big directories and slow
% distributed file systems...
files = regexp(ls(sceneDir), '(\s+|\n)', 'split');
```

gives only

```
files =
{
  [1,1] = a-1300302776.479149-3987628315.dump
}
```

but `ls(sceneDir)` shows all files in the directory. Has anyone experienced this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference is probably not in `regexp`, but in the return value of `ls`. `ls` does not behave the same way in Matlab and Octave when you capture its return value. Matlab's `ls` returns a char row vector (single string as char) with multiple files listed in it as a multi-line string with embedded newlines; Octave's `ls` returns a 2-D char array with one file per line. (IMHO Octave's format is better; it is very difficult to parse Matlab's `ls` output in a reliably correct manner. (That regexp code is not adequate.))

You might just want this in Octave:

```
files = cellstr(ls(sceneDir));
```